# Has anyone had success encrypting an unencrypted SQLite db?

Tags: apache-flex, sqlite

This link: https://github.com/probertson/air-sqlite/blob/DB-copy-dev/src/com/probertson/data/DBCopier.as has an interesting class to do just that! Encrypt an unencrypted database: but I'm having difficulty with a few things:

You can find where the author, @probertson, suggested using his solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606677/sqlite-creating-encrypted-databases-how-the)!

Now I've got the following error:

***Compiler Error:***

```
Error #2044: Unhandled error:. text=Error #3125: Unable to open the database
```

Let me start by saying the source file works, since I've been using it (and the path) in another application.

The error arises in the call to attach the source db to the newly created db.

Any ideas?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. EncrypterProgressPhase class doesn't exist as far as I can tell in his codebase, the owner probably forgot to add it to the git repo.
2. start() will work as long as the the class compiles (see point 1)
3. see point 2

Comment: Check and Check - I just edited while you were typing I think.

Start() is still not recogized.

Comment: Yeah, essentially I need an encrypted pre-populated SQLite db, that includes BLOBs (apparently not supported by Lita)

The other option I have is to create a project to create one in AIR, and then export the created file to my application... obviously I'm exploring other options first.

Comment: Ever thought of maybe trying to *debug* the code?  I mean, looking at the codebase, it's not finished and buggy, but it's not complex.  The source is yours.  Best thing you can do is fork it, fix it, and submit a pull request.

Comment: You're probably right - however I have to acknowledge my limitations. I'll probably just make my db manually as I described before

Comment: Tried working it out - and I've made some progress. However, see current error.

Comment: I think the error is pretty self explanatory.  Either the original db is locked (used) or that the app can't create the new db.

Comment: Best solution: I wrote an application for Air that will automatically create my databases for me.